# How to use vue.js and ejs template engine with express in Node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

I am using Vuejs in my frontend and express in the node server. I have some pages that are rendering through ejs template engine. For example, my home page.

I have built my Vue app and put it in the public folder which is my static folder. I have some express routes like **/** for the Home page, "**/about**" for the About page, etc.

When I visit **/about** route it shows the correct page. But if I try to visit my home page (/) it shows 404 page in my vue app.

```
app.use(pageRoutes);

app.get('*', (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
);
```

All other express routes are working fine. Only home route is not working. I don't know why it is happening. Please can anyone help me?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What's your pageRoutes?

Comment: pageRoutes are the express routes for my serverside render pages.
For example: my home route(/), About route(/about), Privacy policy route(/privacy-policy)